# How to read and use equations for confidence interval from sequential testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, sequential-analysis

in the book "Group Sequential and Confirmatory Adaptive Designs in Clinical Trials" by Wasmer and Brannath - they explain on p.85 how to calculate a confidence interval.

They consider a problem where $H_{0}:\mu=\mu_{0}$ and they are interested in a confidence interval for the standardized effect given by $\delta=(\mu-\mu_{0})/\sigma$.

They in particular say that the bounds for a confidence interval are determined by the following two equations:

$$
\begin{align}
P_{\delta^{L}(z)}(Z\geq z)= \alpha/2 \\
P_{\delta^{H}(z)}(Z \leq z)= \alpha/2
\end{align}
$$

here $Z=\sqrt(n)(\bar{X}-\mu_{0})/\sigma$ and $\delta^{L}(z)$ and $\delta^{H}(z)$ are the respective bounds of the confidence interval.

I have two questions:

1. How do I read these equations?
2. How do I use them to actually compute the c.i.?

Thanks.